# Don’t call subclass methods from a superclass constructor

Tags: java

Consider the following code

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package example0;

/**
 *
 * @author yccheok
 */
public class Main {

    static class A {
        private final String var;

        public A() {
            var = getVar();
            // Null Pointer Exception.
            System.out.println("var string length is " + var.length());
        }

        public String getVar() {
            return "String from A";
        }
    }

    static class B extends A {
        private final String bString;

        // Before B ever constructed, A constructor will be called.
        // A is invoking a overriden getVar, which is trying to return
        // an initialized bString.
        public B() {                
            bString = "String from B";
        }

        @Override
        public String getVar() {
            return bString;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
    }

}
```

Currently, in my mind, there are two ways to avoid such problem.

Either making class A final class.

```
static final class A {
    private final String var;

    public A() {
        var = getVar();
        // Null Pointer Exception.
        System.out.println("var string length is " + var.length());
    }

    public String getVar() {
        return "String from A";
    }
}
```

Or

Making getVar method final

```
static class A {
    private final String var;

    public A() {
        var = getVar();
        // Null Pointer Exception.
        System.out.println("var string length is " + var.length());
    }

    public final String getVar() {
        return "String from A";
    }
}
```

The author trying to suggest ways to prevent the above problem. However, the solution seems cumbersome as there are some rules to be followed.

http://benpryor.com/blog/2008/01/02/dont-call-subclass-methods-from-a-superclass-constructor/

Beside making final and the author suggested way, is there more ways to prevent the above problem (Don’t call subclass methods from a superclass constructor) from happen?

Comment: What exactly was the problem?

Comment: em, what is the problem?

Comment: All that behavior looks perfectly correct. Yes, there's a null pointer exception, but only because you have a method that returns null. That's quite legitimate. What behavior would you like instead? Would you like to fall back on the A variable if B hasn't defined one yet? B can do that on its own.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly with this code ? It's pretty hard to propose anything if we don't know what you want to do exactly.

Comment: In the future please don't include questions or errormessages inside code, but outside code.

Comment: @Yan Proabably the answer on the link is also broken, because the subclass must call `initialize` but what if it doesn't? I think my answer ( making the depending method private ) would be better B-)

Comment: @ Support - multilanguage SO Yes. As I mention, the solution seems cumbersome as there are some rules to be followed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Making getVar method final*

This is definitely what you need to do.

If you're relaying on the functionality of a method to initialize an object, you shouldn't let subclasses broke that method.

Answering your question, **other** way to prevent it is to make `getVar` private in `A`.

See this simplified version of your code:

```
// A.java
class A {
    private final String var;
    public A(){
        var = getVar();
        var.length();
    }
    private String getVar(){
        return "This is the value";
    }
}
class B extends A {
    private final String other;
    public B(){
        other = "Other string";
    }
    public String getVar(){
        return other;
    }
}
class Main{
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        new B();
    }
}
```

BTW, why did you put those as static nested classes, just to create confusion?

Comment: >> static nested classes Sorry. They shouldn't be static. I just want to make some quick call from static main.